# How to define function declaration macro

Tags: c

I have the following problem: I need to define a macro that has to be used instead of using regular C expression.

For example I want this:

```
THREAD(FIRST)
```

... to be substituted by this

```
void THREAD_FIRST(void)
```

... in the code.

I tried with this:

```
#define THREAD(x)    void THREAD_#x(void)
```

... but it didn't work. Maybe the space after `void` is not permitted. Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: What is the motivation to do this? Make the code less readable and harder to debug?

Comment: It does not look to be a good case for macros. So I believe you should not do this. If you think you should, please explain why (so edit your question to improve it).

Comment: Also you do not need `(void)`

Comment: @EdHeal: I prefer to see the `void` in the definition for consistency with the declaration `extern void THREAD_FIRST(void);` where the `void` in the argument list is mandatory (it isn't a prototype otherwise) and the `extern` is optional but I use that too.

Comment: But in the post there is no definitions at all. Only declarations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong preprocessor operator, for token-pasting you want to use `##`, not `#`

```
#define THREAD(x)    void THREAD_##x (void)
```